# Colour letters in a alphabet

Tags: php, if-statement

My code below counts tickets numbers and stores them into arrays based on their alphabet letters. for example a ticket will begin with a letter, X121211 will be store in $X. Then it displays them if the array is not empty. I want to be able to highlight the letters. For example highlight tickets beginning with x in on colour and the rest of the alphabet in another. Is there is dynamic way to do this as this may change weekly. I hope this makes sense.

```
$returned = array();
$returned["A"] = array();
$returned["B"] = array();
$returned["C"] = array();
$returned["D"] = array();
$returned["E"] = array();
$returned["F"] = array();
$returned["G"] = array();
$returned["H"] = array();
$returned["I"] = array();
$returned["J"] = array();
$returned["K"] = array();
$returned["L"] = array();
$returned["M"] = array();
$returned["N"] = array();
$returned["O"] = array();
$returned["P"] = array();
$returned["Q"] = array();
$returned["R"] = array();
$returned["S"] = array();
$returned["T"] = array();
$returned["U"] = array();
$returned["V"] = array();
$returned["W"] = array();
$returned["X"] = array();
$returned["Y"] = array();
$returned["Z"] = array();

   foreach($skin as $x) {
   //    $content .= "<tr>
    //       <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
    //        <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
    //    </tr>";
       $bundletotal += $x[1];
    }
    $bundle += $bundletotal;



    foreach($skin as $x) {
     if (strpos($x[0], "A") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["A"][] = $x;
    }
 if (strpos($x[0], "B") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["B"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "C") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["C"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "D") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["D"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "E") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["E"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "F") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["F"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "G") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["G"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "H") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["H"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "I") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["I"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "J") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["J"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "K") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["K"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "L") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["L"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "M") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["M"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "N") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["N"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "O") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["O"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "Q") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["Q"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "R") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["R"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "S") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["S"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "T") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["T"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "U") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["U"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "V") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["V"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "W") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["W"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "X") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["X"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "Y") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["Y"][] = $x;
    }
     if (strpos($x[0], "Z") !== FALSE) { 
        $returned["Z"][] = $x;
    }

    }   


$A = count(array_unique($returned["A"], SORT_REGULAR));
$B = count(array_unique($returned["B"], SORT_REGULAR));
$C = count(array_unique($returned["C"], SORT_REGULAR));
$D = count(array_unique($returned["D"], SORT_REGULAR));
$E = count(array_unique($returned["E"], SORT_REGULAR));
$F = count(array_unique($returned["F"], SORT_REGULAR));
$G = count(array_unique($returned["G"], SORT_REGULAR));
$H = count(array_unique($returned["H"], SORT_REGULAR));
$I = count(array_unique($returned["I"], SORT_REGULAR));
$J = count(array_unique($returned["J"], SORT_REGULAR));
$K = count(array_unique($returned["K"], SORT_REGULAR));
$L = count(array_unique($returned["L"], SORT_REGULAR));
$M = count(array_unique($returned["M"], SORT_REGULAR));
$N = count(array_unique($returned["N"], SORT_REGULAR));
$O = count(array_unique($returned["O"], SORT_REGULAR));
$P = count(array_unique($returned["P"], SORT_REGULAR));
$Q = count(array_unique($returned["Q"], SORT_REGULAR));
$R = count(array_unique($returned["R"], SORT_REGULAR));  
$S = count(array_unique($returned["S"], SORT_REGULAR));
$T = count(array_unique($returned["T"], SORT_REGULAR));
$U = count(array_unique($returned["U"], SORT_REGULAR));
$V = count(array_unique($returned["V"], SORT_REGULAR));
$W = count(array_unique($returned["W"], SORT_REGULAR));
$X = count(array_unique($returned["X"], SORT_REGULAR));
$Y = count(array_unique($returned["Y"], SORT_REGULAR));
$Z = count(array_unique($returned["Z"], SORT_REGULAR));


     $content .= "
            <table border='5'>
             <td width='50%' valign='top'>
            <p><b>Monday</b></p> <p>";  



    $total = 0; 


     if ($A>0) { 
        $content .= " A: $A "; 
        $total+= $A;

    }

     if ($B>0) { 
        $content .= " B: $B "; 
        $total+= $B;
    }

     if ($C>0) { 
        $content .= " C: $C ";
        $total+= $C;

    }

     if ($D>0) { 
        $content .= " D: $D ";
        $total+= $D;

    }

     if ($E>0) { 
        $content .= " E: $E "; 
        $total+= $E;
    }

     if ($F>0) { 
        $content .= " F: $F "; 
        $total+= $F;

    }

     if ($G>0) { 
        $content .= " G: $G "; 
        $total+= $G;

    }

     if ($H>0) { 
        $content .= " H: $H "; 
        $total+= $H;

    }

     if ($I>0) { 
        $content .= " I: $I "; 
        $total+= $I;

    }

     if ($J>0) { 
        $content .= " J: $J "; 
        $total+= $J;

    }

     if ($K>0) { 
        $content .= " K: $K "; 
        $total+= $K;

    }

     if ($M>0) { 
        $content .= " M: $M "; 
        $total+= $M;

    }

     if ($N>0) { 
        $content .= " N: $N "; 
        $total+= $N;

    }

     if ($O>0) { 
        $content .= " O: $O "; 
        $total+= $O;

    }

     if ($P>0) { 
        $content .= " P: $P "; 
        $total+= $P;

    }

     if ($Q>0) { 
        $content .= " Q: $Q "; 
        $total+= $Q;

    }

     if ($R>0) { 
        $content .= " R: $R "; 
        $total+= $R;
    }

     if ($S>0) { 
        $content .= " S: $S "; 
        $total+= $S;

    }

     if ($T>0) { 
        $content .= " T: $T "; 
        $total+= $T;

    }

     if ($U>0) { 
        $content .= " U: $U "; 
        $total+= $U;

    }

     if ($V>0) { 
        $content .= " V: $V "; 
        $total+= $V;

    }

     if ($W>0) { 
        $content .= " W: $W "; 
        $total+= $W;

    }

     if ($X>0) { 
        $content .= " X: $X "; 
        $total+= $X;

    }

     if ($Y>0) { 
        $content .= " Y: $Y "; 
        $total+= $Y;


    }

     if ($Z>0) { 
        $content .= " Z: $Z "; 
        $total+= $Z;

    }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear and specific about this: "Some weeks have special ticket numbers , lets say v and q. I need to high letters a-v in on colour, v and q in one colour and the remaining in one colour"? It you help us to help you.

Comment: I think the "DRY" principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) needs to be applied here. This kind of copy & paste coding scheme is dangerous, making it very easy for bugs to slip in. Why use an array per letter, when you could use a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: If this is just for visibility, using jquery to add colour can save lots of server processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the exact same thing as the above:

```
$returned = Array();
foreach(array_unique($skin) as $x) {
    $returned[$x[0]] += 1;
}
$total = array_sum($returned);
$content = "";
foreach($returned as $k=>$v) {
    $content .= " ".$k.": ".$v." ";
}
```

It's a heck of a lot simpler than your code.

If this doesn't do what you want, please clarify exactly what you want.